# How do I retain backslashes in strings when using JSON.stringify?

Tags: json

So I got a string that has a backslash in it. `"kIurhgFBOzDW5il89\/lB1ZQnmmY="`.

I tried adding an extra '\', but `JSON.stringify( "kIurhgFBOzDW5il89\\/lB1ZQnmmY=")` returns the string with two backslashes instead of one. Is there any way to keep the backslash using JSON.stringify?

Comment: Why you need `JSON.stringify` a string?

Comment: @xdazz it's part of a larger object which is sent to the server

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` doesn't remove the backslash, it encodes it. When you use `JSON.parse` on the other end, or whatever you do to decode your JSON, it will return the original string.

Comment: The backslash is actually lost in this example.

    `JSON.stringify( { "a": "^sports\..*" } )`
    `{"a":"^sports..*"}`
    `JSON.parse( '{"a":"^sports..*"}' );`
    `Object {a: "^sports..*"}`

Comment: The backslash is not lost due to `JSON.stringify()` or `JSON.parse()`; it is lost because the literal is not well-formed. In other words, `"^sports\..*" === "^sports..*"` is true.

Answer (score 3):

The backslash is escaping the forward slash. So `JSON.stringify("\/")` returns `"/"` since it sees an escaped forward slash, so its just a forward slash. `JSON.stringify("\\/"`) sees a backslash being escaped, and then a forward slash next to that, so it returns `"\/"`. You cannot preserve the "exact" string when you stringify, since parsing a json string will not escape characters, so you get back your original data, just unescaped.

Comment: You're 2nd example is incorrect though.  `JSON.stringify("\\/")` returns `"\\/"` not `"\/"`

Comment: @jk7 maybe my wording was unclear. I'm not saying the result of stringifying `"\\/"` is `"\/"`, I'm saying the result of parsing the stringified string is `"\/"`, ie `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("\/")) > "/"` and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("\\/")) > "\/"`

Comment: yes, that's true.  The problem some of us have is that the stringified string is not going to be parsed by JSON.parse() but rather by server logic and needs to be sent as "\/" instead of "/".  Example: "\/Date(1502450577171+0000)\/"

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("kIurhgFBOzDW5il89\\/lB1ZQnmmY="))
// "kIurhgFBOzDW5il89\/lB1ZQnmmY="
```